# RedHat local repository and offline updates?

Tags: redhat

my company just bought a two redhat license for two physical machines , the machines wont be accessible via internet , so we have an issue here regarding the updates , patches , ... etc .

i am thinking of configuring a local repository to be accessible via internet and have all the necessary updates but there is a problem here that i have only two licenses  , is it applicable if i activate the local repository for the updates and one of my two service machines , or is there any other way like if there is some sort of offline package that i can download it separately from redhat and update my machines without internet access ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- [Red Hat Satellite](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/management/satellite)
- Download the updates on a connected system (using [`reposync`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016))
- Update with new minor release media
- Manually downloading and installing or updating packages
- Create a Local Repository

See [How can we regularly update a disconnected system (A system without internet connection)?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29269) for details.

Comment: Hello Florain 
thanks for the info , but i need to know if i used one of the licenses on the local repository , will the other machine with the non-license will be able to connect to the local repository and get the updates normally ?